# Firebase database specific membership level only monthly access

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a react app with firebase as the backend, using firebase's authentication and real time database. I am planning on using paypal recurring subscriptions and google cloud functions with paypal webhooks to do something like setting some special value in a users database which grants access - say an expiresAt: [next month] field, and then checking against this value for each member to see if they have access, and if not then I need the firebase database to refuse any request for that specific resource. Does this sound reasonable/feasible?

What is the best way to do this, as it seems with firebase Auth your users are stored in a separate users section and its not all put in one noSQL users document where you can add extra properties/fields with extra info like this expiresAt field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to store the subscription expiration times in the Realtime Database as millisecond integers (Stripe gives them to you as seconds by default). Then, in your Security Rules, you could do something like:

```
{
  ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('subscription_expires').val() > now"
}
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks, I'll give it a shot. So I need to create a separate 'users' document in the database and for every user that signs up do a database.ref('users').push({ ...stuff I want to store about new user }) since Firebase auth only creates a basic user entry in the auth section? Where and when is the best place to do this, how do I best use firebases create new user with email and password auth API combined with a larger registration form and a database push? Should I have one form and make two separate async requests?

Comment: You should key the value off of the uid (so it'd be `ref('users').child(auth.uid).set({...stuff})` not `push`). You could also use Cloud Functions with an [Auth onCreate trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) to populate the data.

Comment: @seanEd This looks like a great answer, please accept the answer if satisfied. Also, since it sound you have not started your project yet, I would suggest you look at Firestore as well to avoid possible migration later. I'm migrating my project. This answer should essentially be correct for Firestore too, just need to find the right syntax to set security. Cheers

Comment: Yes thanks a lot, I just wanted to implement it to be sure. Firestore being in beta makes me a bit nervous though the better querying is definitely desirable, is the migration process between the realtime db and firestore difficult?

Comment: I have switched over to using firestore and very happy so far. The documentation helped me achieve what I wanted, specifically - security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions under "access other documents" and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors for easy pagination. Batch insert is also awesome since when I submit new data I create multiple documents at the same time all in one query. Very cool.